# why are C# abstract classes that inherit interface members with the name signature required to implement at least one of them?

Tags: c#, java, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

If an abstract class implements interfaces that declare a member with the same signature, the abstract class can either implement both members or declare one of them abstract and implement the other one.

For whatever reason C# abstract classes (unlike Java abstract classes) can't 'ignore' inherited interface members. But why can't they just declare one of them abstract and then have concrete derived types deal with the implementation of both members?

If that's too ugly or impossible due to some language constraint, then just like concrete classes that inherit interface members with the same signature must explictly implement at least one of them,  why can't abstract classes explicitly declare one of the inherited interface members abstract? Is it for the same reason?

Comment: Did you try any of this out or were you speculating?  What you are asking for has always been possible in C#.

Comment: Perhaps the .net boys took the view that an interface isn't fully implemented when one of it's members is abstract. Seems a reasonable point of view....

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine:

```
interface IFoo
{
  void Foo();
}

abstract class FooBase : IFoo
{
  public abstract void Foo();
}
```

After re-reading the question, I realize we're talking about inheriting multiple interfaces. I'm not sure about that scenario, but seriously, why in the world are you using two interfaces with identically named members. Yuck.

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerator<T>` are perhaps the two most implemented interfaces in .NET, and their inheritance means all implementations implement two interfaces with the same name. Granted it's particularly obvious in those cases how they should be chained, but sometimes one doesn't get to choose what an interface's members are called, because someone else wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

If a class inherits two interfaces with identically-named members but cannot use the same implementation for both, it should typically implement the members explicitly with methods that do nothing but chain to protected methods which may be virtual or abstract.  It is generally a Bad Thing for a derived class to implement an interface which is also implemented by the base.  It is generally better for inheritable classes should generally implement interface using virtual or abstract functions, so derived classes can override those without having to touch the interface.